# Connecting to Google cloud firestore in a cross platform mobile app (xamarin c#)

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Hi I am trying to connect my c# mobile app (Android, iOS) to the google cloud firestore database. The problem I'm running into is that when I'm trying to set up my environment variable, my application can't seem to find the path to the json file which contains the service account key, even though I added the json file into the Android Assets folder, as well as the main project. This is my code:

```
        string path = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "dbfile.json");

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", path);

        FirestoreDb newDB = FirestoreDb.Create("projectKey");
```

But it gives me this error:

System.InvalidOperationException
Message=Error reading credential file from location /data/user/0/.../files/dbfile.json: Could not find file "/data/user/0/.../files/dbfile.json"
Please check the value of the Environment Variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Does anyone know how to properly get the file path in a cross platform mobile app?

Comment: you should place the file in the root of the Android/iOS project with a build action of content, and use a relative path, not a SpecialFolder.

Comment: @Jason do you know what built in functions I should use to get that relative path? I'm not really good with c#

Comment: if it is in your app bundle the path should just be "file.ext" or "./file.ext"

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. I added the json file to the root android and iOS projects with a build action of content and I've tried getting the path using             string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "dbfile.json"); and string path2 = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "test2grow-452ec-3c88d1d6ec8b.json"); but it still can't find the file

Answer (score 0):

If you add the file into `Android Assets` folder,you should read it like below:

```
string content;
AssetManager assets = this.Assets; 
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (assets.Open ("your file")))
 {
    content = sr.ReadToEnd ();
 }
```

You could refer to [Reading Assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows#reading-assets).

Comment: Is there anyway I can use shared C# code to set up the connection for android and iOS to firebase? I have added the json files to the root of all projects but im still getting the same error where it can't find the file.

Comment: Did you set the build action to embedded resource ?