# Error reading credential file from location in xamarin.forms while connecting to Cloud Firestore

Tags: json, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.forms

I am developing a mobile application in xamarin.forms. I will use Google CloudFirestore as Cloud Database. When I want to connect to the database, I get the following error:

*One or more errors occurred. (Error reading credential file from location D:\ yemekbagisiyapbucak.json: Could not find file "/D:\ yemekbagisiyapbucak.json"
Please check the value of the Environment Variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)*

```
public static FirestoreDb db;
path = "D:\\yemekbagisiyapbucak.json";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", path);
db = FirestoreDb.Create("yemekbagisiyapbucak");
```

Comment: your app will be running on a mobile device - how is it supposed to access a file on your `D:\` drive at runtime?  The file actually needs to bundled in your project

Comment: These codes didn't run unfortunatelly, too.   var path = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "yemekbagisiyapbucak.json");
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", path);
                db = FirestoreDb.Create("yemekbagisiyapbucak");

Answer (score 0):

At first, please make sure the .josn file is in the path you set. `var path = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "yemekbagisiyapbucak.json");` get different path on different platforms.

So you can debug it and check the value of the path, and then copy the .josn file to the path.

If you need more information, please check the following link:[Connecting to Google cloud firestore in a cross platform mobile app (xamarin c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66904762/connecting-to-google-cloud-firestore-in-a-cross-platform-mobile-app-xamarin-c)